# importing from sqoop to hdfs Error

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

## I AM GETTING ERROR WHILE IMPORTING FROM SQOOP TO HDFS

INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-root/mapred/staging/root226175073/.staging/job_local226175073_0001
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
        at org.apache.sqoop.config.ConfigurationHelper.getJobNumMaps(ConfigurationHelper.java:65)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.config.ConfigurationHelper.getJobNumMaps(ConfigurationHelper.java:36)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.getSplits(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:125)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:319)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:197)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1297)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1294)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1692)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1294)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1315)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:196)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:169)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:266)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:118)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)

Comment: Its look like version mismatch issue. What is Sqoop and Hadoop version you are using ?

Comment: i am using hadoop 2.6.5 and sqoop 1.4.6

Comment: sqoop 1.4.6 supports 4 major Hadoop releases - 0.20, 0.23, 1.0 and 2.0.